# Exection in Win2D UWP GetsharedDeice in Debug x64 mode

Tags: uwp, win2d

Hi I am getting Exection in Win2D GetsharedDeice in Debug x64 mode

But in release mode its working fine

`CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();`

**Exception:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>      at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>      at Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice()
>   ...
>   ..
>   ..

Can anyone help me to findout cause for this. 
I have used win2d.uwp 1.25 version

Comment: I made a blank sample with the same environment, but I could not reproduce your issue!  please share [mcve] for us.

Comment: Thanks for try. 
I have solved they issue by downloading source code from github and using Win2d project as dependency project.